# How to validate data inside the JSON file

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I'm trying to validate data inside the JSON file in Java. I use Jersey API to get the json file as a JSONObject.

**JAVA:**

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadFile{

  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public JSONObject uploadFileo(JSONObject inputJsonObj) throws Exception {
    validationJSON(inputJsonObj);
    return new JSONObject();
  }
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "user":
    {"username":"Bob!","foo":"whatever","bar":"hello!"},

  "items": [
    {"id":1, "name":"one", "zim":"planet", "gir":"earth"},
    {"id":2, "name":"two", "zim":"planet", "gir":"mars"}
  ]
}
```

But now I have not found the simplest solution yet. If you have interesting approaches, I will be very grateful if you tell me about them. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using json instead of objects? Jersey will map automatically

Comment: Because my JSON file includes several objects and their connections.

Comment: Can you describe a sample json and what kind of validations you want on top of it. It will help to get the right and concise answer

Comment: Use a POJO and [bean validation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html). This is the preferred way

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org).

You write the validation rules in a schema file (in Json format) and then call a Schema validator.  The one I use is this [Jackson based implementation](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator). However, it works on Jackson's `JsonNode` not on `JSONObject` (which I don't know where it comes from).